# Is there a legitimate reason Amazon probes /admin

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, web-crawler, ip, probe

From my raw server logs, I found these:

```
52.42.136.103    02/Aug/2016:17:58:12    GET /administrator/
54.234.186.225   03/Aug/2016:16:48:55    GET /administrator/
54.149.57.2  04/Aug/2016:18:40:55    GET /administrator/
52.40.119.32     06/Aug/2016:09:34:37    GET /administrator/
52.40.119.32     08/Aug/2016:06:02:45    GET /administrator/
```

The ip's all belong to Amazon Technologies (and I don't have an /admin directory).

I'm used to seeing that kind of random probe thing (/wp-admin, /wp-blog/, /dir, ... ) from Russia and Vietnam and so on, and I've always assumed there was some nefarious motive behind it. Is there? Why would Amazon be doing that? Is Jeff Bezos out of control?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon itself is not crawling your site but more likely to be some of their EC2 users (i.e. rented servers on the cloud). See below for email address to contact Amazon if you think their users are doing something illegal or abusive

```
whois 52.40.119.32 

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=52.40.119.32?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       52.32.0.0 - 52.63.255.255
CIDR:           52.32.0.0/11
NetName:        AT-88-Z
NetHandle:      NET-52-32-0-0-1
Parent:         NET52 (NET-52-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Amazon Technologies Inc. (AT-88-Z)
RegDate:        2015-09-02
Updated:        2015-09-02
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-52-32-0-0-1

OrgName:        Amazon Technologies Inc.
OrgId:          AT-88-Z
Address:        410 Terry Ave N.
City:           Seattle
StateProv:      WA
PostalCode:     98109
Country:        US
RegDate:        2011-12-08
Updated:        2014-10-20
Comment:        All abuse reports MUST include:
Comment:        * src IP
Comment:        * dest IP (your IP)
Comment:        * dest port
Comment:        * Accurate date/timestamp and timezone of activity
Comment:        * Intensity/frequency (short log extracts)
Comment:        * Your contact details (phone and email) Without these we will be unable to identify the correct owner of the IP address at that point in time.
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/AT-88-Z


OrgTechHandle: ANO24-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Amazon EC2 Network Operations
OrgTechPhone:  +1-206-266-4064 
OrgTechEmail:  amzn-noc-contact@amazon.com
OrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ANO24-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: AEA8-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Amazon EC2 Abuse
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-206-266-4064 
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@amazonaws.com
OrgAbuseRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/AEA8-ARIN

OrgNOCHandle: AANO1-ARIN
OrgNOCName:   Amazon AWS Network Operations
OrgNOCPhone:  +1-206-266-4064 
OrgNOCEmail:  amzn-noc-contact@amazon.com
OrgNOCRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/AANO1-ARIN
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. And I can pretty much assume they are at least hoping to abuse, right? No legit reason to send an /admin probe I can think of, and don't see how it could be by accident. (Of course "probe" just sounds ominous)